# Allow Full screen only in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen

How can I make it, that my app only opens in fullscreen? So maybe you can make it smaller but the best way is to enable it only fullscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something along the lines of `[window toggleFullScreen:nil];` to your `- (void) awakeFromNib` method, and it everytime your application starts, it will enter fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.m file find applicationDidFinishLaunching:
call toggleFullScreen: method

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.window toggleFullScreen:self];
}
```